# How to Parse sync data between devices?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Is it possible to make for example a chat app using parse, in a way that when 1 device sends a message to the other device, the other device will recieve it instantly, without using any timer.

Which means Parse will somehow send the other device the message when it sees that somthing changed in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

> "You can't get realtime without using an external solution, but it's pretty easy to add an external service like PubNub to make it happen."

Long answer and source: http://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-use-Parse-com-for-realtime-chat-like-Socket-io

Answer (score 1):

You can send push to the second device which will trigger second device reloading request from database. You can write Cloud code that will send pushes every time that something would change in your database

Answer (score 0):

Like how Zen mentioned, it is very easy to implement and include realtime functionality into your application by using an external solution like PubNub. You can use Parse for the user management features and file storage, and let PubNub take care of the realtime communication features.

Original answer sourced from : [Realtime Collaboration Sync with Parse API and PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/realtime-collaboration-sync-parse-api-pubnub/)

[image]

[**PubNub**](http://www.pubnub.com) provides Data Stream Network for delivery of realtime messages such as long-held HTTP Streaming connection, HTTP Long-Polling, XMPP, BOSH, Comet and WebSockets with Push Notifications for backgrounded or closed apps while [**Parse**](https://parse.com) takes care of core user management features and basic file storage.

When you combine Parse API and PubNub, you can create user interactivity in realtime like chat, document and photo sharing while using these platforms as your toolset. You will need these systems to auto scale to millions of users, if needed, and deployable quickly and iteratively.

By combining the Parse API with PubNub Data Streams you can obtain the ultimate developer toolkit powerful enough to scale your successful mobile app to billions of users. Using the Parse API for user management with large file storage and PubNub for data streams, you can  power live user communication to your app supporting both iOS and Android.

So in short :

- PubNub – Realtime Message Delivery & Push Notifications like APN
- Parse API – Shared file & image storage

**Parse + PubNub Publish Messages: Publishing messages from Parse.com Cloud Code via PubNub**

You can publish messages inside of parse cloud to your mobile users to create chat experiences easily. If you want to send the messages directly from within Parse Cloud, use the following code to send a message to a user.  You can achieve this by using Parse HTTP Requests.